# react-native-google-places-autocomplete (Search for shops)

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-api

I'm working on a project for my final year at university and I managed to implement this library 'React-native-google-places-autocomplete' on my react-native expo but ideally, I wanted to search for shops/stores. It seems like I can only search for addresses.

Please, I would appreciate any guidance. is it the case that 'React-native-google-places-autocomplete' does not support search stores? If not, would you recommend any library that allows this functionality? I have also made use of google maps API.

Kind regards,

Comment: This apparently seems to be a API provided by google but not sure if it works with react native (expo) still investigating.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search

Comment: `React-native-google-places-autocomplete'` is a wrapper component on top of Google Place API. You can use Google Place  JavaScript SDK on your Expo Project with more freedom of filtering the content you want

Comment: You can fork and refactor this package with your own filters -  https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/GooglePlacesAutocomplete.js#L119